# Very strange error when importing images to Eclipse

Tags: android, image

I found a very strange and anoying bug.
Im developing in Eclipse, i use several images for my app.
Sometimes when i import a new image to the project and use it somewhere in my app, after the test run all the images are went to another places... Its like every image has changed their resource ID and they are all moved to another places... background loads for buttons, button image loads for scrollbars.. etc... every image is bugged and appear in random places!

Nothing can solve this bug, except deleting my app manually, then run again.
I work on my phone, not Emulator.

It is really annoying, i dont want in the future that when im updating in market, the users will get a messed up app...

Anybody know something about this?

Comment: Try using project->clean... after you have changed many resources. This rebuilds the R class with all the id's.

Comment: Not solving the issue.. sadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are importing any image make sure that the name of the images in not in `Capital letter` and also its name doesn't start with any `numeric value`. Otherwise its going to create problem in generating its id in R.java.

Comment: I accepted your answer but in case, i dont use Capital letter or numeric value in file names :(

Answer (score 2):

That's probably because the R.java is messed up.. try to do Project->Clean and see if that solves the problem

Comment: It is not solving it. Only solve: Delete app from phone manually, then reinstall.